# Validating XML against XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a complex XML File that I need to build for a data submission to a 3rd Party.

They have provided me 2 Schema's relating to the document in question which I have placed in:

http://www.fresh.co.uk/twschemas/Common.xsd

http://www.fresh.co.uk/twschemas/PCPolicy.xsd

I wish to validate my XML against these XSD. Now I am using XMPLIFY for MAC to do this and the FAQ tells me I should declare a target namespace, the root element of my XML document and use the following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root xmlns="http://example.com/namespace"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/namespace
                      http://example.com/schema.xsd">
</root>
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PolicyInput xmlns="http://www.tradewisebrokerexchange.com/schemas/2012/10" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fresh.co.uk/twschemas/Common.xsd">
```

But I am receiving a validation error stating:

```
Element '{http:www.tradewisebrokerexchange.com/schemas/2012/10)PolicyInput': No matching global declaration available in the validation root.
```

I am fairly new to XML and I haev validated against XSD's before but only 1 XSD where as there seems to be 2 XSD's for this particular file.

All help is appreciated please as I do not wish to keep sending my XML to the 3rd party for them to tell me its wrong so I need to correctly validate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `PolicyInput` does not occur in either of your XSD's, so it is invalid, hence you get the validation error.

If you have to deal with more than one XSD, then these only make sense if these import each other in some. This seems to be the case. The main XSD is `PCPolicy.xsd`, which imports `Common.xsd`. The net effect is that anything declared in `Common.xsd` is available to anybody using the `PCPolicy.xsd`.

Next step is to make sure that your schema location is correct. In your case, you write:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fresh.co.uk/twschemas/Common.xsd"
```

This is not valid. The schemalocation is a space-separated list of URIs and namespaces, that pairwise have to locate the physical location of your XSD. I.e.:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tradewisebrokerexchange.com/schemas/2012/10 file:/D:/Projects/tests/SO_PCPolicy.xsd">
```

But this won't help you, because neither schema has an element defined, it only defines types. What you need is a schema that defines an element of a given type from these schemas. I think your documentation is not (yet) complete and that you are missing a schema that actually uses these types, or the schemas you showed are not finished yet.

Until you have an element in a given type, there is not much you can do and anything you validate against these schemas will always fail.

For instance, if I create the following XSD:

```
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://www.tradewisebrokerexchange.com/schemas/2012/10"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:pcp="http://www.tradewisebrokerexchange.com/schemas/2012/10"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:include schemaLocation="SO_PCPolicy.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="root" type="pcp:PCAdjustment"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and call it `PolicyImpl.xsd`, I have now created an element `root` of type `PCAdjustment`. Now I can actually start creating my XML:

```
<pcp:root 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="test"
    xmlns:pcp="http://www.tradewisebrokerexchange.com/schemas/2012/10"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tradewisebrokerexchange.com/schemas/2012/10 file:/D:/Projects/tests/PolicyImpl.xsd">

    <pcp:PolicyNumber></pcp:PolicyNumber>

</pcp:root>
```

This is still not valid, but at least now I get meaningful validation errors:

- cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type 'PolicyNumber'.
- cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '' of element 'pcp:PolicyNumber' is not valid.
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'pcp:root' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.tradewisebrokerexchange.com/schemas/2012/10":EffectiveDate}' is expected.

I know nothing of your requirements, so you'll have to check documentation or suppliers for how to actually apply these schema's meaningfully.

Slightly OT: use an editor that can do real-time validation and give you context-sensitive help. I prefer [`oXygen`](http://oxgyenxml.com), but there are quite many free (Eclipse) and non-free available.

Comment: You were spot on, followed what you said now that I had an idea of what I was looking for. There was an extra file missing as you say. Top man, thank you.